# How to make a 'npm run build' from a symfony project

Tags: php, symfony, zurb-foundation

I currently have a symfony project that uses Foundation for Emails to create responsive emails.

The Foundation framework uses the command 'npm run build' to tranform files. I tried doing a service parse my content using the Process class but I must be using it wrong as it does not execute 'npm run build'. Here is my faulty code :

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: jeremie
 * Date: 28/12/17
 * Time: 16:59
 */

namespace Acme\Open4XMLParserBundle\Services;

use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;


/**
 * @todo : code this
 */
class FoundationParser
{
    protected $foundationLocation;
    protected $process;

    /**
     * FoundationParser constructor.
     * @param $foundationLocation
     */
    public function __construct($foundationLocation)
    {
        $this->foundationLocation = $foundationLocation;
        $this->process = new Process('npm run build', $this->foundationLocation);
    }

    /**
     * Run npm run build if needed
     */
    public function initFoundation()
    {
        //make sure that 'npm run build' is running and execute it if not
        if (!$this->process->isRunning()) {
            $this->process->start();
        }
    }

    public function saveFoundationContent($foundationContent, $filename)
    {
        //save the file in foundation/src/pages
        $fileSystem = new Filesystem();
        $fileLocation = $this->foundationLocation . '/src/pages/' . $filename;
        if (!$fileSystem->exists($fileLocation)) {
            $fileSystem->dumpFile($fileLocation, $foundationContent);
            $fileSystem->chmod($fileLocation, 0664);
        }
    }

    public function retrieveValidHtml($fileName)
    {
        $fileLocation = $this->foundationLocation . '/dist/' . $fileName;
        while (true) {
            try {
                $result = file_get_contents($fileLocation);
                if ($result !== false){
                    return $result;
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I use my service like this :

```
$foundationParser = $this->container->get('open4xmlparser.foundationparser');
$foundationParser->initFoundation();
$foundationParser->saveFoundationContent($foundationContent, 'test.html');
$response = new Response($foundationParser->retrieveValidHtml('test.html'));
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
$response->send();
```

And it tells me that 'test.html' does not exist. Any idea on how to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I finally decided to do is a Symfony command that launch my program in an infinite loop(it is never supposed to stop). Instead of using a service I executed 'npm run build' directly in the while loop.

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $output->writeln([
        '',
        'Running program',
        '===============',
        ''
    ]);
    $runBuild = new Process('npm run build', $this->getContainer()->getParameter('foundation_location'));

    while (true) {

        if (!$runBuild->isRunning()){
            $output->writeln([
                '',
                'Executing npm run build',
                ''
            ]);
            $runBuild->start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have different paths in the `saveFoundationContent` and `retrieveValidHtml` for the target file.

```
// saveFoundationContent()
$fileLocation = $this->foundationLocation . '/src/pages/' . $filename;

// retrieveValidHtml()
$fileLocation = $this->foundationLocation . '/dist/' . $fileName;
```

Obviously, `retrieveValidHtml()` cannot find the file in the location.

Tip: Store the subdirectory path as a class variable (or constant):

```
class FoundationParser
{
    private $subdir = "/dist/"; // or "/src/pages/";

    … 

    public function retrieveValidHtml($fileName)
    {
        $fileLocation = sprintf("%s%s%s", $this->foundationLocation, $this->subdir, $fileName);
        …
    }
}
```

Comment: I must have explained my issue badly.  Foundation is parsing the file located in /src/pages and put in a NEW file located in /dist. My issue is that the command 'npm run build' that does the parsing is not getting started. The code works just fine when I do that command by hand but I wanted to make it in php. The 'npm run build' script is actually watching any changes inside the /src folder and making the appropriate changes inside the dist folder. So I need to run it asynchronously. Anyway you are right about making the location a constant/class variable and I will most certainly do that.